# Segmentation fault when trying to get string from input

Tags: c++, string, input, segmentation-fault, scanf

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  char *s;

  printf("enter a word \n");

  scanf("%s", s);

  int i;

  for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
  }

  printf("length is = %d", i);

  return 0;
}
```

When I compile this program, a segmentation fault occurs.

Can anyone plz tell me, what is the problem in this code?

Comment: You're trying to put `char`s in the memory locations pointed to by `s`. Where does `s` point?

Comment: If it has a compiler error please edit the question and add the exact text of the compiler error. I believe there may not actually be a compiler error but instead a runtime error because of the undefined behavior caused by not initializing `s`. With that said if this is `c++` why are using `char *`, scanf(), and `printf()` it's much simpler and less error prone if you use modern `c++` instead of `c` code compiled in a `c++` compiler.

Comment: You are including the wrong header for the functions that you are using. For example `printf` is defined by `cstdio`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *s;
```

Is unitialized, you can't assign an input stream to it until it is.

```
char s[100]; //space for 99 characters plus null terminator
```

or

```
char* s = malloc(100); //each char has the size of one byte
```

These are C tools, for C++, however, you can/should use `std::string`, with `std::cin` instead of `scanf`.

```
std::string s;
std::cin >> s;
```

If you must use C tools, `scanf("%s", s);` is not the most safe method, if you don't pass the size of the `char array` container, changing  specifier `%s` to `%100s` or changing it altogether to a safer function like `fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);` is a better option.

Comment: If the OP would keep  `scanf` and tries to use `std::string` there, without resizing the string before, the same problem would exist. So it should be mentioned that if you use `std::string` you should also consider to switch to `std::cin >>`

Comment: @FireLancer, that is true,

Comment: @anastaciu I got corrected here that `%ns` with a width (e.g. `%100s`) is a thing so can technically be done, but should probably mention. Also playing with macro's (or worse variables) to insert the right size in the format string isn't going to be pretty.

Comment: @FireLancer, yes it's an option, it will limit the size, so I guess it's safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *s;
```

You created a pointer, though it does not point to anything (it is uninitialized).

```
scanf("%s",s);
```

You try to read data into the string pointed-to by `s`, but no such thing exists.

!

Allocate some memory and have `s` point to it… or, better yet, use `std::string` and `std::cin`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> char *s;
>
> printf("enter a word \n");
>
> scanf("%s",s);
> ```

`scanf` with `%s` does not allocate memory, instead it reads into the buffer you provide it (e.g. `s = malloc(100);`. How big does that buffer need to be to avoid a buffer overflow? Unfortunately it can be however long until a whitespace character, so is inherently unsafe.

You can specify a max up front (not including null terminator!), but to handle variable size you then need to dynamically build the format string which gets complicated. As does what to do if the user enters a string too long.

```
char s[100];
scanf("%99s", s);
```

Since you tagged C++, you can use `std::string` and IO streams (e.g. `std::cin` for console input) which will handle all the memory allocation for you.

```
std::string s;
std::cout << "enter a word" << std::endl;
std::cin >> s;
```

In the case of C, you might use `fgets(str, num, stream)`, this lets you specify the max length and avoid overflow in a simple manner.

```
char s[128];
fgetsf(s, 100, stdin);
```

Or with the POSIX 2008 `scanf` it *can allocate the memory*, but I don't believe this is universally supported, e.g. by Microsoft Visual Studio.

```
char *s = 0;
scanf("%ms", &s); // pass a pointer to a pointer!
free(s); // needs to be freed later!
```